# laravel mocks with multiple shouldReturn() statements

Tags: php, laravel, mocking, phpunit

I am trying to create a laravel mock which has two shouldRecieve() statements

Something like this

```
$mock = $this->mock(Service::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {

$mock->shouldReceive('init')->once();

$mock->shouldReceive('process')->once();
});
```

ive tried several variations but no matter what it try it only mocks one of the functions

shouldrecieve can take multiple arguments as an array but if I do this there is no apparent way to set a different set of asserts/function ( once(), with(), andReturns() ect ) to each mocked function

I am  instantiating Service::class with the laravel service container
ie

```
App::make(Service::class);
```

How can I make this work

Comment: Can you edit your question with additional details about how you are instantiating `Service::class`? Can you also try to call `init` and `process` right after the mock? Ty

Comment: I am  instantiating Service::class with the laravel service container
ie

    App::make(Service::class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is awesome how this awesome library do not explain that you can send a second argument to `::mock` like a `closure` and it will do something... Awful documentation...

The [documentation](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html#) does not say anything, so to discard this behaviour, try doing it the normal way, instead of your code, try this one:

```php
$mock = Mockery::mock(Service::class);

$this->bind(Service::class, function () use ($mock) {
    $mock->shouldReceive('init')->once();
    $mock->shouldReceive('process')->once();

    return $mock;
});
```

Comment: That was helpful
although i found out what the issue is and gave my own answer in the main thread

Comment: In my case, I should use `$this->app->bind()` instead of `$this->bind()` in Laravel 6.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this

The problem was that my Service::class has a ServiceBuilder::class
and once the service builder class is instantiated a function which returns an instance of service builder runs before the functon which returns service

something like this

```
$serviceBuilder = App::make(ServiceBuilder::class)
$servieBuilder = $serviceBuilder->setup();
$service = $serviceBuilder->build();
```

To make this work This code

```
$mock = Mockery::mock(Service::class);

    $this->bind(Service::class, function () use ($mock) {
        $mock->shouldReceive('init')->once();
        $mock->shouldReceive('process')->once();
    
        return $mock;
    });
```

had to become

```
$builderMock = Mockery::mock(ServiceBuilder::class);
$mock = Mockery::mock(Service::class);

    $this->bind(ServiceBuilder::class, function () use (builderMock) {
        $builderMock->shouldReceive('setup')->once()->andReturn($builderMock);
        $builderMock->shouldReceive('build')->once()->andReturn($mock);
    
        return $builderMock;
    });
```