# Mockery Partials Still Receiving All Methods in Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpunit, mockery

I have a simple function that cleans strings imported from a CSV. It is a method on a Laravel service, and I am using it in a console command I am testing.

```php
class myService implements MyServiceInterface {
    public function cleanString($string) {
        if(is_null($string)) return $string;
        return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 -_!@#$%^&*\(\)\\\|\'\"\;\:]/', '', $string);
    }
}
```

I have several other methods from `myService` mocked.

```php
class ImportTest extends DBTest {
    protected $fileUploadService;
    protected $realFileUploadService;

    public function setUp(): void {
        parent::setUp();

        $testData = array(full of stuff);

        //Mock the  service
        $this->mock = $this->partialMock(MyServiceInterface::class, function (MockInterface $mock) use ($testData) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('method1')->andReturn(null);
            $mock->shouldReceive('method2')->andReturn($testData[0]);
            $mock->shouldReceive('method3')->andReturn(count($testData) - 1);
            $mock->shouldReceive('method4')->andReturn(array_slice($testData, 1), false);
        });
    }
```

I thought that the partial mock would ignore the `cleanString` method calls, but every time I run the tests, I get:

```
Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException: Received Mockery_5_App_Services_Interfaces_MyServiceInterface::cleanString(), but no expectations were specified
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```php
class MarkelClaimImportTest extends DBTest {
    protected $fileUploadService;
    protected $realFileUploadService;

    public function setUp(): void {
        parent::setUp();

        $testData = array(full of stuff);

        $mock = Mockery::mock(MyServiceInterface::class)->makePartial();

        $mock->shouldReceive('method1')->andReturn(null);
        $mock->shouldReceive('method2')->andReturn($testData[0]);
        $mock->shouldReceive('method3')->andReturn(count($testData) - 1);
        $mock->shouldReceive('method4')->andReturn(array_slice($testData, 1), false);

        $this->app->bind(MyServiceInterface::class, $mock);
    }
```

Check if that works. I am saying this because [I recently helped someone with something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68911298/laravel-mocks-with-multiple-shouldreturn-statements/68915270) and it seems that `$this->mock()` and `$this->partialMock()` are not working as expected.

---

Also, super small and personal tip: Follow [PSR (PHP Standards Recommendations)](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#:%7E:text=5.1) (and [ternary operator](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#:%7E:text=6.3)), your service file is not correctly standardized. It should be like:

```php
class myService implements MyServiceInterface
{
    public function cleanString(?string $string) : ?string
    {
        return $string ?
            preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 -_!@#$%^&*\(\)\\\|\'\"\;\:]/', '', $string) :
            $string;
    }
}
```

And if you still want to use the `if`, write `{ }`, avoid 100% one line `if` without `{ }`. In that case use [ternary operator](https://stitcher.io/blog/shorthand-comparisons-in-php#ternary-operator) `expression ? true, what to return? : false, what to return ?`;

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I'm getting errors with the bind method, `Call to undefined method Tests\Feature\Console\ImportTest::bind()`

Comment: Also, as I posted this I noticed I should be using ternary logic, thanks for writing it out. I actually didn't realize null values would be truthy :)

Comment: @qotsa42 if you get an error like `Call to undefined method Tests\Feature\Console\ImportTest::bind()` that means you are not extending from `Tests\TestCase`, where is `DBTest` extending from ? It should work as it is normal Laravel behaviour. And `null` evaluates to `false` when casted to `boolean`, no problem with that !

Comment: @qotsa42 where you able to fix this with my comment ?

Comment: sorry. Thought I replied, must not have pressed send. My class extends another class which extends Tests\TestCase.

Comment: @qotsa42 I am really sorry, I wrongly wrote `$this->bind` it is `$this->app->bind`... You can use `$this->app->bind` or `$this->instance` (that last one exists like that). See my updated answer...

Comment: it did not. I ended up rewriting some of the methods since it was requiring all methods be mocked.